# NodeJs,Canvas UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported image type

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, png, jpeg

```
Dependency : 
canvas > version: 2.6.1
node   > version: 12.12.62
```

I am trying to do bellow :

```
   const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
   var image = await loadImage("png.png");
```

But, the same piece of code is perfectly working for *.jpeg file type.

Checked all possible points still having bellow error :

```
(node:2536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported image type
    at setSource (********\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:91:13)
    at Image.set (********\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.js:62:9)
    at ********\landmark-detection\node_modules\canvas\index.js:34:15
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at loadImage (********\node_modules\canvas\index.js:23:10)
    at imageReconstruction (********\landmark-detection\app.js:159:22)
    at ********\app.js:102:36
(node:2536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js 
process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Is it an actual PNG file?

Comment: Yes it is, I verified that  @ChrisG  added this to github issues also . https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1677

Comment: fixed  now ..had issues with image file itself after further validation we just found out that