# How to fix unsupported image type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, discord.js

```
//constant
const wlcmimg = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/996549250882220113/1005125013998936064/bg.png"
//code
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  if (member.guild.id === '1003114703796576348') {
    const { loadImage, createCanvas, registerFont } = require('canvas');
    const canvas = createCanvas(1024, 500);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
    registerFont('./fonts/virgo.ttf', { family: 'virgo', weight: 500 });
  
    const pfp = await loadImage(
      member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "jpg" })
    )
  
    const background = await loadImage(wlcmimg);
    let x = 0
    let y = 0
    ctx.drawImage(background, x, y, 1024, 500)
  
    x = canvas.width / 2 - 125;
    y = canvas.height / 2 - 200;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - 75, 125, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#400080';
    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(pfp, x, y, 250, 250);
    ctx.restore();
  
    ctx.font = "85px virgo";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.shadowColor = "white"
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0; // integer
    ctx.shadowBlur = 10; // integer
    ctx.fillText("WELCOME", 308, 380);
  
    ctx.font = "40px virgo";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText(member.user.tag, 360, 430);

    client.channels.cache.get('1003118559045632060').send({content: `Hello **${member}**`, files: [wlcmimg]}) 
}})
```

Error: Unsupported image type

I already saw many tutorials and several forums but that error still exists, if someone tells me how I can solve it I would be grateful, I am a beginner in this and I would like you to help me please

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329955/nodejs-canvas-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-unsupported-image-type - if you test it using a different image in JPG format, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to require "MessageAttachment" from the discord.js library and send the attachment that way.

To use MessageAttachment():

```js
const attachment = new MessageAttachment(
'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/996549250882220113/1005125013998936064/bg.png'
);
```

To send an MessageAttachment:

```js
//normal command:
message.channel.send({files: [attachment] })
//or
message.reply({files: [attachment] })
//interaction
interaction.reply({files: [attachment] })
```

Comment: ReferenceError: MessageAttachment is not defined

Comment: Make sure you import `MessageAttachment` from `discord.js` by doing this => `const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js")`

Comment: yeah as i said at the top of my message, require MessageAttachment from the discord.js library

Comment: MessageAttachment is not a constructor

Comment: how are you sending the message? If you are adding text send it like this `message.channel.send("Hello There", {files: [yourAttachmentHere]})`

Comment: client.channels.cache.get('1003118559045632060').send(`¡Welcome**${member}**!`, {files: [attachment]}) 


That's OK?

Comment: Should work, although the ! and the upside down ! should be backticks.

Comment: Still the same "MessageAttachment is not a constructor"